# Filter nested dictionary in python based on key values

Tags: python, dictionary

How do I filter a nested dictionary in python based on key values:

```
d = {'data': {'country': 'US', 'city': 'New York', 'state': None},
     'tags': ['US', 'New York'],
     'type': 'country_info',
     'growth_rate': None
     }
```

I want to filter this dictionary to eliminate NoneType values so the resulting dict should be:

```
d = {'data': {'country': 'US', 'city': 'New York'},
     'tags': ['US', 'New York'],
     'type': 'country_info',
     }
```

Also, the dict can have multiple levels of nesting. I want to remove all NoneType values from the dict.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can define this recursively pretty easily with a [dict comprehension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY).

```
def remove_keys_with_none_values(item):
    if not hasattr(item, 'items'):
        return item
    else:
        return {key: remove_keys_with_none_values(value) for key, value in item.items() if value is not None}
```

Recursion isn't too optimised in Python, but given the relatively small number of nestings that are likely, I wouldn't worry.

Looking before we leap isn't too Pythonic, I think it is a better option than catching the exception - as it's likely that the value will not be a `dict` most of the time (it is likely we have more leaves than branches).

Also note that in Python 2.x, you probably want to swap in `iteritems()` for `items()`.

Comment: I like your answer, and this may be a little nitpicky, but it reads betters as `if value is not None`.

Comment: @BrianHicks Noted and fixed, very true.

Comment: I guess if we're trying to be more pythonic, you should either use `if hasattr(item, 'items')` or just assume it's being passed a dictionary. You can pass `[1, 2, None]` to the function as is and get back the same item with nones.

Comment: @BrianHicks I don't think the intention was to remove `None` from lists - I presumed this was purely to remove keys with values of `None`. `hasattr(item, 'items')` is probably a little better too, this is true.

Comment: @Lattyware: Why does the link 'dict comprehension' link to a YouTube video about list comprehension? Because it's close enough?

Comment: @benregn The video goes on to talk about other types of comprehensions and generator expressions.

Comment: How about a version that works in Python 2.6 (long story)? The last line has a syntax error in 2.6, which I assume was some change in how comprehensions worked in 2.7.

Comment: @machomeautoguy dictionary comprehensions didn't exist before 2.7 - you can replace it with a call to `dict()` with a generator expression producing tuples, I.e: `dict((key, value) for x in y)`

Answer (score 0):

I really appreciate the answer by @Lattyware. It helped me filter out a nested object and remove empty values regardless of type being `dict`, `list`, or `str`.

Here is what I came up with:

### remove-keys-with-empty-values.py

```
# remove-keys-with-empty-values.py
from pprint import pprint

def remove_keys_with_empty_values(item):
  if hasattr(item, 'items'):
    return {key: remove_keys_with_empty_values(value) for key, value in item.items() if value==0 or value}
  elif isinstance(item, list):
    return [remove_keys_with_empty_values(value) for value in item if value==0 or value]
  else:
    return item

d = {
     'string': 'value',
     'integer': 10,
     'float': 0.5,
     'zero': 0,
     'empty_list': [],
     'empty_dict': {},
     'empty_string': '',
     'none': None,
    }

d['nested_dict'] = d.copy()
l = d.values()
d['nested_list'] = l

pprint({
  "DICT FILTERED": remove_keys_with_empty_values(d),
  "DICT ORIGINAL": d,
  "LIST FILTERED": remove_keys_with_empty_values(l),
  "LIST ORIGINAL": l,
})
```

### execution

```
python remove-keys-with-empty-values.py
    {'DICT FILTERED': {'float': 0.5,
                       'integer': 10,
                       'nested_dict': {'float': 0.5,
                                       'integer': 10,
                                       'string': 'value',
                                       'zero': 0},
                       'nested_list': [0,
                                       'value',
                                       10,
                                       0.5,
                                       {'float': 0.5,
                                        'integer': 10,
                                        'string': 'value',
                                        'zero': 0}],
                       'string': 'value',
                       'zero': 0},
     'DICT ORIGINAL': {'empty_dict': {},
                       'empty_list': [],
                       'empty_string': '',
                       'float': 0.5,
                       'integer': 10,
                       'nested_dict': {'empty_dict': {},
                                       'empty_list': [],
                                       'empty_string': '',
                                       'float': 0.5,
                                       'integer': 10,
                                       'none': None,
                                       'string': 'value',
                                       'zero': 0},
                       'nested_list': [{},
                                       0,
                                       'value',
                                       None,
                                       [],
                                       10,
                                       0.5,
                                       '',
                                       {'empty_dict': {},
                                        'empty_list': [],
                                        'empty_string': '',
                                        'float': 0.5,
                                        'integer': 10,
                                        'none': None,
                                        'string': 'value',
                                        'zero': 0}],
                       'none': None,
                       'string': 'value',
                       'zero': 0},
     'LIST FILTERED': [0,
                       'value',
                       10,
                       0.5,
                       {'float': 0.5,
                        'integer': 10,
                        'string': 'value',
                        'zero': 0}],
     'LIST ORIGINAL': [{},
                       0,
                       'value',
                       None,
                       [],
                       10,
                       0.5,
                       '',
                       {'empty_dict': {},
                        'empty_list': [],
                        'empty_string': '',
                        'float': 0.5,
                        'integer': 10,
                        'none': None,
                        'string': 'value',
                        'zero': 0}]}
```